# What is a library that can create popovers/popups in the spot that you click?

Tags: open-source, library, javascript

I am trying to create a site that will allow for a popup to appear right where the user clicks.  Are there any existing open source libraries that work well with this?

Similar to this link (scroll down and press contact us) [Example](https://obvious.com/team)

Comment: Pressing contact us doesn't show a popup in the same spot for me...

Comment: Something like [OverLib](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221060009/http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib)? Unfortunately the original URL seems down. Very likely that OverLib is no longer that useful with nowadays HTML and CSS3 capabilities.

Answer (score -1):

You can take this question to stackoverflow and figure out how to make it with HTML + CSS + JS, it shouldn't be too hard; certainly doesn't need a dedicated js library.

Just to give you a basic idea: use the onclick event on whatever scope you want, so for instance if you want the pop up to be able to happen anywhere on your page, the onclick event should be in the body tag.

Then in JavaScript grab the x and y coordinates of the click with 
event.clientX, and event.clientY.

Then you simply have to generate an absolutely positioned pop up with x and y margins equal to these x and y values.

Comment: Library questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Also "please program this for me" questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Maybe it doesn't need a library, but OP wants one - and why not? Building such a library that works across all browsers may be a hard task. [OverLib](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221060009/http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib) e.g. did a great job for me and I was really pleased to not implement it myself.